# Getting nr of days the app was used through firebase cloud functions

Tags: android, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics, usage-statistics

Hi I'm developing an app where i collect user walking distance throughout the day in the background when app is active. So far it only calculates total and stores this in firestore database. Now I would like to give the user a running daily average (over a period) that updates when total value updates in firestore. So daily_average = total_distance / nr_days_app_app_was_active/used.

Of course i could do this on the device but I would like to try to make a cloud function that calculates this. But is there a good way to collect the nr of days the app was used / opened from firebase analytics, firebase authentication or should i have my own counter on device to send signal when app is active or use the android app usagestats ? Usagestats could maybe measure my notification foreground app but then it makes a lot of millisecs over a year.. :)

It's totally ok that nr_days_app_used only indicates they have had the app active at least short time during the day and not necesserily 100% of the day and if it would be possible from firestore function / analytics it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication doesn't provide historical information, so won't be of use here on its own.

Analytics:

1. If you want to know whether the user opened the app, consider checking the [standard `screen_view` or `session_start` events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en) from Analytics.
2. If you want to instead detect whether the user was active/took steps, you can log a custom Analytics event whenever you detect activity.

You could define an audience for those, but there is no API to query those audiences. What you *can* do there is export your Analytics data to BigQuery, and perform the necessary query there.

But I suggest you consider whether that is really al that helpful, when compared to simply writing the active days to Firestore. The latter is much closer to the data you already have.